# Need to replace multiple HPHL and HPHR with same values

Tags: notepad++

Hello I am new to notepad++ and I am editing a s8+ set of mixer_paths.xml files.

There are two known values HPHL and HPHR the problem is they appear 282 times across 7 files all with this starting line HPHL value="3" on one line and HPHL value="15" on other lines and so forth.

How do I make notepad++ search for HPHL value="(different values)" and replace all those with this line HPHL value="20"?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you add an extract of the files and expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use in Notepad++ as following.

- Find what: `^HPHL value="\d+"`
- Replace with: `HPHL value="20"`
- Search mode: Regular expression

Do the same for `^HPHR value="\d+"`